# ASP.NET core start dependency injection at when app is started

Tags: asp.net-core

I am injecting one of my services as last item in the ConfigureServices method:

`services.AddSingleton<IBot>(_ => new De.Impl.Bot(Configuration));`

I am running the app in docker container so whenever container is restarted I need to invoke my controller so I can get my service running. How can I get it running in the beginning of the configuration part?

Comment: I don't understand your question. You don't "start Dependency Injection". If you have some sort of background service you want to run within your app, you'd use a [Hosted Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). There's lots of documentation on how to set that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As for .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5.0

First, you can write your business code as an extension:

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public static IHost DoSomething(this IHost host)
{
    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        var yourService = services.GetService<YourService>();
        yourService.DoSomething();
    }

    return host;
}
```

So if you want to invoke that method every time your application starts, simply call:

```cs
    // .NET 5.0 Style
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .DoSomething()
            .Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
    }
```

### As for .NET 6.0

It's gonna be easier. Simply access `var yourService = app.Services.GetRequiredService<YourService>` in the `Program.cs`.

```cs
// .NET 6.0 style, in Program.cs, before app.Run();

var yourService = app.Services.GetRequiredService<YourService>();
yourService.DoSomething();

app.Run();
```